# Which are the variable naming rules in Processing?

Tags: variables, syntax, processing

(Question by John Williams, from a Coursera forum, which I decided to share with the community, since I haven't been able to find this answered anywhere.)

The following code runs without error:

```java
int _j = 1;
//int 2var = 2;
int var2 = 2;
int Kvar = 3;  // first letter can be uppercase
int spec$var = 4;
int com_pound_var = 5;  // compounding without camel case
int com$pound$two = 6; 
int $var = 199;
println(_j);
println(var2);
println(Kvar);
println(spec$var);
println(com_pound_var);
println(com$pound$two);
println($var);   //first character can be special
```

Since the compiler accepts `_j`, `Kvar`, and `$var` as valid variable names, it is clear that variable names do not need to start with a lowercase letter.

I was unable to locate the variable naming rules anywhere in the reference.

**What are the variable naming rules for the Processing language?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer: can start with any letter, underscore and dollar signs, continue with letters, numbers, underscore and dollar signs. Details below.

---

I could also not find anything in the reference or the documentation at all. However, inspecting the source code, I found that Processing is not a language of its own, but rather a framework in which you run some commands. The difference is that you're actually writing a different language, and Processing just gives you some basic scaffolding where you build on top of.

For some technical details: Processing compiles a Java Build with some flags, spins up a virtual machine (Java VM, not same thing as a full fledged virtual machine) and connects to it to get input and output streams (this is why you can interact with the mouse or get the console output of your own program in a separate window). ([Source](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/9ddf676233f97ba78ba217f76c7ba8ca541f385d/app/src/processing/mode/java/runner/Runner.java#L106).)

This language, which you may have guessed already, is Java.

With that said, the actual docs that answer this question is the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8), which, to simplify things, is as close as you can get to an answer. (But if you really want to know, [it's a mess](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/175085/33790).)

Specifically, the section on [Identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8), which I'll sum up below:

- Can start with any letter (`A-Z`, `a-z`), underscore (`_`), dollar sign (`$`), or any unicode "letter" (accented, chinese, etc. [Details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart(int)).)
- Can continue with any of the above, and can also continue with digits (`0-9`). Can also contain other unicode "letters" ([Details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart(char)).)
- Can have unlimited length
- Cannot be any Java keyword ([list here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9))
- Cannot be `false`, `true`, `null`
- They can look the same and still be different if their codes are different (some Unicode letters look just like letters but are different ones)

I hope this helps! Investigating was fun.